# Return a rectangle from an rectangle intersection?

Tags: actionscript-3, math, intersection

Been struggling to come up with a solution to return a rectangle representing the actual intersection between two rectangles.

What I am looking for is much like this:
[MSDN - Rectangle::Intersect Method (Rectangle, Rectangle)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y10fyck0.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-2)

As the picture shows I would like to have the rectangle colored in green returned from an intersection between two rectangles.  Not some boolean value true or false.

[image: Rect intersection data]

I will accept a code sample or just plain theory as an answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: On [gamedev.se], I found [What is the fastest way to work out 2D bounding box intersection?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/586) which appears to be the same question.

Comment: Hmm or maybe that is just for the yes/no question. Anyway, I suggest this is probably asked and answered somewhere on [gamedev.se]

Comment: Thanks for the reply but as you later stated that was a simple rect intersection stating TRUE or FALSE.  I am looking for the actual intersected rect area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
r3.minX = max(r1.minX, r2.minX);
r3.maxX = min(r1.maxX, r2.maxX);
r3.minY = max(r1.minY, r2.minY);
r3.maxY = min(r1.maxY, r2.maxY);
```

Converting to and from your actual representation of Rectangle is an exercise for the reader.

If `r3.minX > r3.maxX || r3.minY > r3.maxY`, there is no intersection.  Otherwise, if `r3.minX == r3.maxX || r3.minY == r3.maxY`, the resulting rectangle is degenerate.  Otherwise, you have an actual intersection with positive area.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!  Seeing this now it makes perfect sense.  Accepted :)

Comment: just FYI: calculation with min/max almost twice slower than using intersection method because of more function calls, I added the benchmark to my answer )

Comment: OK. (When I answered, the question was also tagged [c++].)

Comment: Hey this is good to know.  I tagged the question as C++ as that is what I am working with but also AS 3.0 since it is easy to transfer AS 3 code to C++.  I would have accepted answers from both languages.

Thank you both!

Answer (score 6):

Check out the [Rectangle.intersection()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Rectangle.html#intersection%28%29) method it is what you need.

benchmark `intersection` vs `min/max` calculation:

```
    var t:int = getTimer();

    var r3:Rectangle = new Rectangle();
    var r1:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
    var r2:Rectangle = new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100);
    var i:int;

    for(i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        r3.left = Math.max(r1.left, r2.left);
        r3.right = Math.min(r1.right, r2.right);
        r3.top = Math.max(r1.top, r2.top);
        r3.bottom = Math.min(r1.bottom, r2.bottom);
    }
    trace("min/max: t = ", (getTimer() - t), "ms");

    t = getTimer();
    for(i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        r3 = r1.intersection(r2);
    }
    trace("intersection: t = ", (getTimer() - t), "ms");
```

out:

```
min/max: t =  167 ms
intersection: t =  87 ms
```